Need help to find problem with custom editor in DevExpress XAF Blazor (v.23.xx)
I have created a class (Business Object), which holds some properties for article information and a list of it's own.
The basic idea is: I want to enter articles and save them into a list.
One of the properties is bound to a custom XAF Blazor editor.
I am starting to show the business object as DetailView.
With a button, I am adding the current information into the list property.
After that, I click on one of the list items, a new DetailView is opened.
When I now click on the custom editor, the dropdown get's showed in the first DetailView (wrong position), where the custom control is, not in the new DetailView.
For better understanding, I have created a litte video: Video
I have created a custom editor in XAF (to be specific a DxCombobox) which should show data in a custom dropdown layout.
Therefor, I followed the official DevExpress instructions.
DevExpress Documentation
I talked to the DevExpress support, but they don't help with custom editors. I have to find the problem and report it to them, when I know what the problem is.
To be honest, I don't find the problem - I haved debugged everything with the information from here
I have created a small and easy project to reproduce the problem:
Github repository
Maybe someone of you has experience to find such issue and can help me to report the problem to DevExpress.
THX a lot in advance

After a lot of research and help, I found the problem.
It ended with a official bug report at DevExpress.
DevExpress Portal
So, my problem got solved.
Don't know, why the question was voted -1, but anyway - THX for all the private help I got
